# Validation message doesn't always display below the input

Tags: html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have the following snippet:

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <small>
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

In some situations the validation message is not displayed below the input but right next to it. How can I force the message to be displayed below the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put validation error message outside `<div class="input-group">`:

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <small>
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </small>
</div>
```

result:
[image]